# Get page location with React Router 4 and Hash routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to get the location of the page I'm on in order to set up conditional rendering. Originally, I had something set up like this

```
const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
...
<h1>{currentPath}</h1>
```

And that would echo out the path as `http://example.com/page`.

But since I've switched to using HashRouter, and page links are generated like `http://example.com/#/page`, the only thing that echoes out is "/"

How do I get the location of the page after the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Route` in React-router v4 passes three props to the component it renders. One of these is the `match` object. It contains information about how the current path was matched.

In your case, you can use `match.path` or `match.url` to get the location of the page.

Something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Route, HashRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Child = ({ match }) => {
  return <p>{match.url}</p>;
};

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Child} />
      <Route exact path='/test1' component={Child} />
      <Route exact path='/test2' component={Child} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Working code is available here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/3xj75z41z1

Change the route in the preview section on the right to `/` or `/test1` or `/test2`, and you'll see the same path displayed on the page.

Hope this helps. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to use `match.url` in class components?

Comment: You're welcome! :) `match` is just a prop passed by the `Route` component. In a class component, it would be available to you at `this.props.match.url`

Answer (score 0):

React Router provides location parameter out of box.

You can access it like `location.pathname`

For eg: if the component is Page:

```js
const {HashRouter, Route, Link} = ReactRouterDOM;
function Page({location}) {
  return <p>{location.pathname}</p>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path="/page" component={Page} />
          <Link to='/page'>Link to Page</Link>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

Comment: While that makes sense, but I keep getting a `Unexpected use of 'location'` error that only goes away unless I use `window.location`, which again, only returns "/" for all hash routes. Also, how would I pass location as a parameter in react component classes?

Comment: It is already a prop if the component is in the route. You are getting `Unexpected use of location` because you are not using the prop, but trying to access the global object.